# Why is there an error when merging a branch that says "there was a problem with your editor"?

Tags: git, sublimetext3

I got an error when trying to merge a branch called "alien-plot".

The error says that there's a problem with my editor, and that it can't find a file related to Sublime.

My terminal output:
[image: terminal output]

Comment: Have you previously been able to make commits/merges from the command line?

Comment: Assuming you have sublime installed, can you try: `$ git config --global core.editor "'C:/Program Files (x86)/sublime text 3/subl.exe' -w"` (Source: https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/associating-text-editors-with-git)

If you have `nano` installed, you could also try `git config --global core.editor nano`.

Comment: See "[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812)".

Answer (score 0):

Check your configuration with `git config -l -show-origin` for any `core.editor`  set.

You can, if you don't have SublimeText, unset it

```
git config --global --unset core.editor
cd ~/Desktop/Story
git config --unset core.editor
```

Then the default editor with git for Windows should be `vim`.
You can retry the merge.